# is it possible to make parameters in sub-report visible in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I have a main report with parameters and passing those parameters to sub-report.

[image]

But when sub-report displays - all parameters are hidden in report manager, so no way to choose any parameters in sub-report.

[image]

My question is: even though you passing parameters from main report to sub-report, are there any ways to still see the parameters in sub-report and be able to choose values and run this sub-report with different value parameters?

Comment: Do you mean a sub report that is embedded in your main report or a drill through report that is opened when you click on something in your main report?

Comment: Sub report, that embedded in my main report.

Comment: This is impossible.

Comment: Your action is go to report so actually by clicking you open another report. That is not a subreport which is a report embedded and used in the main report

Comment: Can you run your rptOpenTasks directly by choosing it's parameters or are they all hidden?

Comment: Yes, I can run rptOpenTasks directly, and none of the parameters are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need to have Cascading parameters. I'm not sure I can understand the use case for your current setup, but it looks like you are running a report to see certain records, then choose another parameter to further narrow down your results.

You can have multiple drop down parameters where based upon the first parameter you choose, it will automatically filter the second parameter to show you values based on the first. These parameters would reside on your main report, and possibly eliminate the reason for the sub-report?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255197.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I assume you realize that you can expand and collapse the parameters pane in the report viewer.  I also assume you are referring to a drill through report (as indicated by the settings screen you've included), despite your comment to the contrary.

In your screenshot, you have the parameters pane collapsed, which I believe is the default behavior when opening a drill through report.  To my knowledge, this default can't be changed on a setting in the rdl itself, but users can be easily trained to simply expand the pane after opening the report.

Comment: I would have to test this out but if you omitted a required report parameter (did not supply a value) could the drill down report still load but with the parameter pane expanded for user input?

Comment: No, the parent report will error out if the Action does not include all parameters required by the drill through report.

Comment: Ah, make sense though.